# Is it possible to use Selenium WebDriver to drive PhantomJS?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, phantomjs

I’m going through the documentation for the Selenium WebDriver, and it can drive Chrome for example. I was thinking, wouldn't it be far more efficient to ‘drive’ PhantomJS?

Is there a way to use Selenium with PhantomJS?

My intended use would be web scraping: The sites I scrape are loaded with AJAX and lots of lovely JavaScript, and I’m thinking this setup could be a good replacement for the Scrapy Python framework that I’m currently working with.

Comment: I notice there is an internal class
`PhantomJSDriver : RemoteWebDriver, ITakesScreenshot`
but you cant create an instance of it (yet)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

PhantomJS now includes the [GhostDriver project](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver).

You are also suggested to use PhantomJS directly or with a convenience library such as [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org). CasperJS is specifically designed to make it easy to do sequential operations to web pages, perfect for many automation tasks.

Disclaimer: I am the author of PhantomJS.

**Edit**: As noted in Nick's answer, GhostDriver is now included in PhantomJS.

Comment: Oh wow Ariya responded, I was reading some of your stuff the other day, I really admire your work. This is kinda awesome, anyways, if you don't mind, whats the best way to incorporate PhantomJS/CasperJS into a application. I was thinking of using Selenium because I want the whole program to loop and run continually (its real time and slightly interactive) When I was going throgh Phantom documentation I got the impression it's a command line tool for one off uses, and calling it from python would allow me to make it into a full program. Any tips?

Comment: You can take some inspirations from a lot of PhantomJS user articles (check the wiki).

Comment: The wiki is empty. Any clues where I can get help on making this work with PHP?

Comment: @Joseph: regarding the 'one off uses' issue, I also ran into that and created PhearJS for that (https://github.com/Tomtomgo/phearjs). It wraps a pool of PhantomJS instances and provides you with an API to it.

Answer (score 20):

@Joseph, since the 1.8 release GhostDriver is included in the stable release of PhantomJS. Here is the exact release notes: http://phantomjs.org/release-1.8.html. 
You can simply start PhantomJS process to listen on some port, like this:

```
phantomjs --webdriver=PORT
```

Kudos to @detro and PhantomJS team for awesome work!