# The selenium turned off running on the server

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium, cross-browser

We have existing selenium tests in many projects but these were turned off
due to problems running selenium on the server. Selenium has been updated
a few times since then but it may be that the underlying problem is that
we were continually re-launching firefox.
i want to know if there is any other browser which i can keep running at backend and no need to open every time which sometime slow the server and at worse hang it.
please suggest some solutions.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: You may be interested in PhantomJS which is a headless browser with a selenium webdriver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226648/is-it-possible-to-use-selenium-web-driver-to-drive-phantomjs

Comment: How slow is slow? What problems are you having? You've literally said nothing about the issues the tests are having.

Comment: sometime server is hanging so have to restart it,its not about tests but also about the server which is getting slow because of the firefox instances fired up everytime  !!@Arran